# Ionic 2 : "Property 'number' does not exist on type 'typeof"

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, ionic2

I write a new post about a problem to give more details.

I try to create a class in my ionic 2 project, I use this code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'field.html'
})

export class test {
    x : number;
    constructor(x : number){
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

I want to use it in my other component. It's work when in compile it with "ionic serve" in my terminal. But when I try to compile on my android phone I have this error :

```
[09:54:06]  Error at C:/xampp/htdocs/AppFineMobile/.tmp/classes/fieldSpecs/test.ngfactory.ts:42:71
[09:54:06]  Property 'number' does not exist on type 'typeof
            "C:/xampp/htdocs/AppFineMobile/.tmp/classes/fieldSpecs/test"'.
[09:54:06]  ngc failed
[09:54:06]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[09:54:06]  Error: Error

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ build script 'ionic-app-scripts build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\AppFineMobile\npm-debug.log
```

I don't understand why. First I try the same code on a provider file, but same problem.

Someone have any idea please ?

Comment: Instead of doing that, just use `constructor(private x : number){ //... }`. By doing that you don't need to declare the `private` property in the component, since typescript is declaring it for you.

Comment: Ok thanks I have change that. But it's not the solution. :)

Comment: Of course, that's why it's just a comment and not an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution, but I think it's not what I really have to do :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'field.html'
})

export class test {
    x : number;
    constructor(){}

    initClass(x : number) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

My constructor stay empty and I write parameter on another method. It's work, but if someone have the true correction of my problem I say yes ! :D

Answer (score 2):

When a class is decorated with `@component` , the classes are created by angular's `Dependency Injection` framework where   it tries to find providers from the type of the constructor parameters as key to find one.

Primitive types like `string`,`number`, `boolean`, `Object` don't work as keys. I am not sure why it didnt fail with `ionic serve`. You can learn more about `DI` [here.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)

Comment: It's work with ionic serve because it not compile with NGC.

Comment: Might have something to do with run time compilation.